# Fixed focus on legend item click

Tags: c3.js

I have a multi series line chart with a lot of rows. I like the focus API to fade the other data points without removing them from the chart (it allows for quick comparison).

Right now, when a user hover on some legend item, the item will be highlighted and the rest faded to grey. The problem with this is that I can't first hover an item and then go to the chart to see the tooltips because, obviously, there's not a hover anymore.

So what I'd like to do is to click on a legend item and "fix" or select the item, fading (not hiding) the others.

This is what I have right now:

```
var chart_test = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#charttest',
    data: {
        type: 'spline',
            x: 'x',
            columns: [
              //DATA 
            ]
    },
    legend: {
             item: {
                 onclick: function (d) { 
                       chart_test.select(d);
                       chart_test.focus(d);
                 }
             }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it, just enable selection and prevent the defocus event from being called when your mouse does not hover the legend anymore.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chartid'
    data:{
     ....
     selection: {
          enabled: true
     }
    },
    legend: {
           item: {
                onclick: function (d) { 
                       chart.focus(d);
                       chart.select(d);
                 },
                 onmouseout: function(d){
                       // prevent deselect onmouseout
                 }
           }
    }
});
```

The only thing left is some logic when your user is selecting another item or wants to unselect the current selection.

Comment: The below function can be removed, since on mouseout last hovered item was active and chart default view was not loading properly.                            
   onmouseout: function(d){
                       // prevent deselect onmouseout
                 }